# deleting rows depending on the datetime in date column in csv file in python

Tags: python, date, csv, datetime

Im new here, so hello.
Ive tried to find similar issues but i didnt. So maybe its gonna be helpful to other not experienced coders like me.

I have CSV file in such structure:

```
This is the list of workers.
Company blablabla.
name^position^start_date
John^manager^2015-01-01 08:00:00.0
Mary^supervisor^2014-10-01 09:00:00.0
Lucas^worker^2013-01-01 12:00:00.0
etc...
```

i need the script to:
- delete First three rows becasue are not needed,
- ask the user for the start date, 
- then the script will delete all the rows which have "older or equal date" then user was asked for in previous step
- and finally leave only the names (1 column) and save it to the same csv file.

What i come up with till now:

## deleting the rows 1,2 and 3:

```
import os

directory = ('C:/TEMP/')
os.chdir( directory )

FIRST_ROW_NUM = 1  # or 0
ROWS_TO_DELETE = {1, 2, 3}

with open( directory + 'FILE.csv', 'rt') as infile, open('FILE-NEW.csv', 'wt') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(row for row_num, row in enumerate(infile, FIRST_ROW_NUM)
                        if row_num not in ROWS_TO_DELETE)
```

## reading the CSV file, delimiting and sorting

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

f = open('FILE-NEW.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f,delimiter='^')
csv_f = sorted(csv_f, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

now im stuck and i need to ask the user for the date but even if i'll add a variable with the static date, how should i use it to compare with the date column to delete the rows with older date?
THanks for any help.
Greets

Comment: Welcome to SO! "if row_num not in ROWS_TO_DELETE" is ugly. It's just sequential counting needed to skip those lines, not any cross-product search.

Answer (score 0):

The basic ideas were accurate, but you did not exploit the sequential ordering.

Of course, you need not generate the data file; I do this for readers who want to test this code; you may also want to add `try-except` when processing external files.

```
import os
import sys
import uuid
import csv
from datetime import datetime

CONTENT = """This is the list of workers.
Company blablabla.
name^position^start_date
John^manager^2015-01-01 08:00:00.0
Mary^supervisor^2014-10-01 09:00:00.0
Lucas^worker^2013-01-01 12:00:00.0"""

DT_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"

FIRST_LINE = 3
START_DATE = datetime.strptime("2014-10-01 09:00:00.0", DT_FORMAT)


IN_FILENAME = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.txt'
OUT_FILENAME = 'FILE-NEW.csv'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(IN_FILENAME, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(CONTENT)

    with open(IN_FILENAME, 'r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile.readlines()[FIRST_LINE:],
                            delimiter='^')
        reader = sorted(reader,
                        key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(
                            row[2], DT_FORMAT
                        ))

    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='^')
        # more efficient than filter because reader is already
        # prooperly sorted
        for row in reader:
            if datetime.strptime(row[2], DT_FORMAT) < START_DATE:
                continue
            writer.writerow(row)

    with open('FILE-NEW.csv', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            print(line[:-1])
```

output:

```
Mary^supervisor^2014-10-01 09:00:00.0
John^manager^2015-01-01 08:00:00.0
```